# Отследить изменение размеров элемента в Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Есть всплывающее окно в котором по клику можно добавлять контролы. 
Если количество контролов больше высоты экрана, то нужно добавлять скролл.

Как в Angular и где ( в каком хуке) лучше отслеживать высоту блока с контролами, чтобы добавить скролл?

Самое очевидное для меня решение - через @ViewChild('controlsBlock') получать блок с контролами, брать у него высоту через nativeElement.offsetHeight, сравнивать ее с высотой окна и если она превышает, то добавлять стиль overflow: scroll блоку с контролами.

На сколько это правильный подход?

Comment: хуки относятся к этапам рендеринга, но не к изменениями стилей и тд.

Comment: высота сама по себе тоже не может меняться, что происходит чтоб изменилась высота?

Comment: по клику на кнопку в попапе добавляется новые контролы, которые растягивают высоту. Вы считаете , что высоту по клику нужно считывать? Я просто хотела, чтобы высота постоянно слушалась в каком-то хуке

Comment: я вам объясняю что хуки не отслеживают стили элементов :) у вас есть метод который обрабатывает клик на кнопку, вот в нем и меняйте стиль элемента `overflow`, сделайте отдельный метод который что-то проверяет и просчитывает, и вызывайте его в методе обработки события `click`

Comment: Я же не стили собиралась отслеживать в хуке, а высоту блока :) Но это наверное ресурсозатратно, постояннно слушать ее
Спасибо за совет, поняла ))

Comment: У меня не получается изменять только в методе. Мне нужно по-любому где-то следить за высотой блока с контролами т.к. первоначальный размер попапа, где они лежат также зависит от количества предварительно выбранных контролов. Т.е. я в основном окне выбираю количество нужных мне контролов,  подтверждаю, открывается попап и оттуда я дополнительно могу добавлять контролы - с этим все ок. Но если я первоначально выбираю все контролы то они не помещаются в окно.

Comment: вы можете использовать `ResizeObserver`, но он поддерживается только в хроме и опере. Вам не нужно "следить" за высотой, это невозможно, но любые манипуляции с DOMом заставляют использовать нативные средства браузера :) я кстати не понимаю зачем вы все так усложняете, я уверен что это можно решить с помощью нативного CSS и не дергать сам Angular + JS

Comment: Только CSS не получилось) JS-ом вроде выходит